# Interface and Implementation

Tags: go, interface

In following code snippet -

```
type Input interface {
    Name() string
}

type Abc interface {
    Do(Input)
}

type InputImpl struct {
}

func (InputImpl) Name() string {
    return "sample-impl"
}

type AbcImpl struct {
}

func (abcImpl *AbcImpl) Do(input Input){
    // do something
}
```

`AbcImpl` struct is an implementation of `Abc` interface, but changing last function like this -

```
func (abcImpl *AbcImpl) Do(input InputImpl){
    // do something
}
```

Now the `AbcImpl` is not implementing `Abc` anymore, though `InputImpl` is implementing `Input` interface !

Am I missing something or it's compulsory to have **exact same signature** (not event Impls) as the interface to be a legitimate implementation?

Comment: Yes, it is compulsory to have exactly the same signature. Is there any reason why you want define it like this?

Comment: @bereal ok, I was trying to create a factory somewhere in my code, where I found this problem.

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work in any language because now Do can't accept all types of Input anymore but that's required by the Abc interface.

Comment: Thats what I realised soon after putting the question :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, **you do have to follow the method signature you specified**.
If you don't follow the signature, it will not be called "implementing".

an example: [interface example](https://gobyexample.com/interfaces)

from tour of Go: `There is no explicit declaration of intent, no "implements" keyword.`

---

Answer (score 1):

It is compulsory to use the very exact same signature when implementing an interface in Go. You can't implement it otherwise.